# Is it ok to delete the 3DP folder?

Tags: windows

So I have a windows 10 dell laptop which is 64 bit and recently I was going to my **C:** drive to delete the windows.old folder but I noticed another folder called **3DP** with another folder inside it called **Net** and I wanted to delete this folder as I am not familiar with it and what it does so it is okay to delete 3DP folder?

Comment: What is inside the net folder? If there are drivers in there, leave em be. If the folder doesn't take up much space, just ignore it. Probably this thing: https://download.cnet.com/3DP-Net/3000-2112_4-10915115.html

Comment: Also, rename it and see if anything breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete it if you wanted too but it has a copy of your ethernet/wifi drivers in there. Always a good idea to make a copy of those drivers to a safe place offline incase you need to reinstall your OS again. 3DP is a software program which installs drivers.